# Can not stop render previos Screen1() after setScreen(new Screen2());

Tags: java, libgdx

I have two identical classes: Screen1 and Screen2. The problem is that when I open Screen2 from Screen1 the animated sprite of Screen1 continues to render. I see it in the log. And after a while memory overflow occurs. How to stop rendering a closed screen?

```
public class Screen1 extends Game implements Screen, InputProcessor {

    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private TextureAtlas atlasBarrelBlue;
    private Sprite sprite1;
    private float sprite1positionX;
    private float sprite1positionY;
    private float spriteBarrelWidth;
    private float spriteBarrelHeight;
    private Texture backgroundTexture;
    private Animation<TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion> animationBarrelBlue;
    private float dTime = 0;
    private Vector2 vector2;

    @Override
    public void show() {

        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        vector2 = new Vector2();
        atlasBarrelBlue = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("data/barrels/barr4"));
        animationBarrelBlue = new Animation<TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion>(1 / 24f, atlasBarrelBlue.getRegions(), Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);

        spriteBarrelWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 50 * 4;
        spriteBarrelHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 50 * 11;
        backgroundTexture = new Texture("data/fones/fone1.png");

        sprite1positionX = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 50 * 7;
        sprite1positionY = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 50 * 32;

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        dTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

        sprite1 = new Sprite(animationBarrelBlue.getKeyFrame(dTime, true));
        Gdx.app.log("111", "111");
        sprite1.setPosition(sprite1positionX, sprite1positionY);
        sprite1.setSize(spriteBarrelWidth, spriteBarrelHeight);

        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(backgroundTexture, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        sprite1.draw(batch);
        batch.end();

        super.render();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        atlasBarrelBlue.dispose();
        backgroundTexture.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

        vector2.set(screenX, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - screenY);
        if (sprite1.getBoundingRectangle().contains(vector2)){
            setScreen(new Screen2());
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Dyspose() and hide() methods do not help. When i go from Screen2 to Screen1 the same thing happens.

Comment: Where is your `create()` method? When you extend Game you need a `create()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you extend Game, implements Screen and call `super.update()`.

libgdx will call the `render` method of the Game class.
While the Game class holds a screen and call the `render` method of the current screen you set with `setScreen()`.

When we look at the `render` method of the `Game` class:

```
@Override
public void render () {
    if (screen != null) screen.render(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
}
```

`screen` is the screen you have set with `setScreen()`

So Libgdx call => Game.render() and Game.render() call => Screen.render(float delta)

---

Now when we look on your code. You override the method: `render(float delta)` which is the render method of the Screen. (The render method of the Game has no parameter).

So first libgdx call `Game.render();` this calls the render method of Screen1 and at the end of your overridden Screen1.render(float delta); method, you call again the Game.render() function with `super.render();`.
So you recursively call the `Screen1.render(float delta);` method. This is the reason why you become a memory overflow.

I will recommend you to not extend Game and implement Screen in the same class
The class which will be created in the DesktopLauncher should extend Game.
In my case TextAdventure:

```
public class TextAdventure extends Game {

    @Override
    public void create () {
        setScreen(new Screen1(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        super.render();
    }
}
```

And in the Screen1 class only implements Screen and don't call `super.render()`!:

```
public class Screen1 implements Screen {

    Game myGame;

    public Screen1(Game myGame) {
        this.myGame = myGame;
    }

    public void changeToScreen2(){
        myGame.setScreen(new Screen2(myGame));
    }

    ...
}
```

To change the Screen in Screen1 pass the Game class in the Constructor.